# How can I fix a .dll file?

Tags: windows-7, dll

A  problem with DLL file in windows 7

I use a Accounting Software after format this error appear the program from safenet company :

> Run time error 53:
>   File not found: Ux32w.dll

Comment: Could we get any info about when exactly this happens? When did that problem start to occur?

Comment: According to my google-fu, this file is a module from SafeNet, Inc. Though your question didn't really include ANY information, I'd guess you need to reinstall whatever product from them you're trying to run when you get this error.

Answer (score 6):

Either re-install the program (the program with the missing .dll) or copy the individual .dll into the appropriate folder from another source (if for example a friend/colleague also has the program).

Comment: And BEWARE of the amount of "DLL Download" sites searching for this stuff on Google turns up. Downloading executable code from untrusted sources online is asking for big trouble.

Comment: To further on Xyon's sensible comments, there are numerous sites offering fixes for your exact issue (just Google your issue); I have not used/tested any of these sites (hence the recommendation from a friend/colleague) and if it were me, I would rather install the software than try a fix from an unknown source!